# How can I get the HierarchicalLayout graph to render properly?

Tags: java, graph, graphstream

I am using the Graphstream library to create a visual representation of a Tree structure.
[Current view of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiXcd.png)

But the nodes are all clumped together. What can I do to make the graph look like -> [Image for Manually arranged nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTbul.png).
Is there a way to store node positions from graph to a file and then load them when the application is running?